# Asking help updating batch parser

Tags: loops, search, batch-file, dos, text-parsing

I have a question about the following batch file:
it does it's work perfectly but i'm wondering if the following is possible:

Is there any way for it to let it look in several directories and output the file in that specific directory and then continues to the next until it reached the end of the directory list and then finishes.

So for example:

```
main dir  -subdir
          -subdir1
          -subdir2
          -ect.
```

i start the batch in maindir and it will list the files each subdir in an outputfile.rss in that subdir. so it will look like this:

```
main dir  -subdir - outfile.rss (contains the list of files of this subdir)
          -subdir1- outfile.rss (contains the list of files of this subdir)
          -subdir2- outfile.rss (contains the list of files of this subdir) 
          -ect.
```

And this is the batch file i would like to "expand".
Hopefully someone can help me with this?

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "header1=<rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">"
SET "header2=    <channel>"
SET "footer1=    </channel>"
SET "footer2=</rss>"

(
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO(!header1!
ECHO(!header2!
ECHO(
ENDLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (*.flv *.mp4) DO (
    ECHO(    ^<item^>
    ECHO(        ^<title^> %%~na ^</title^>
    ECHO(        ^<jwplayer:source file="/temp/records/%%~nxa" /^>
    ECHO(    ^</item^>
)
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO(
ECHO(!footer1!
ECHO(!footer2!
)>outfile.rss
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


REM calculate the length of local path 
FOR /L %%n in (1 1 500) do if "!__cd__:~%%n,1!" neq "" set /a "len=%%n+1"

SET "header1=<rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">"
SET "header2=    <channel>"
SET "footer1=    </channel>"
SET "footer2=</rss>"


(
    ECHO.!header1!
    ECHO.!header2!
    ECHO.

    FOR /R %%a IN (*.flv *.mp4) DO (
        SET "absPath=%%a"
        SET "relPath=!absPath:~%len%!"
        SET "webPath=!relPath:\=/!"
        ECHO.    ^<item^>
        ECHO.        ^<title^> %%~na ^</title^>
        ECHO.        ^<jwplayer:source file="/temp/records/!webPath!" /^>
        ECHO.    ^</item^>
    )
    ECHO. 
    ECHO.!footer1!
    ECHO.!footer2!
) & REM put "> file.rss" here if you want a file 

ENDLOCAL
```

You are a bit on the edge of what is useful to do in batch scripting. You would be much better off using a real scripting language like python, powershell or javascript. Especially if you ever need to extend this more.

Answer (score 0):

See if this does what you need:

```
@echo off
 for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
    pushd "%%a"
       for %%b in ("%cd%") do call :rss "%%~nxa"
    popd
 )
goto :eof
:rss
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "header1=<rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">"
SET "header2=    <channel>"
SET "footer1=    </channel>"
SET "footer2=</rss>"

(
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO(!header1!
ECHO(!header2!
ECHO(
ENDLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (*.flv *.mp4) DO (
    ECHO(    ^<item^>
    ECHO(        ^<title^> %%~na ^</title^>
    ECHO(        ^<jwplayer:source file="/temp/records/%~1/%%~nxa" /^>
    ECHO(    ^</item^>
)
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO(
ECHO(!footer1!
ECHO(!footer2!
)>outfile.rss
```

Comment: Thank you verry much, this solution does exactly what i wanted.
Have a nice day mate.